# NFe Paulista CURL

Tags: php, nfe

Estou tendo o seguinte problema para realizar a emissão de nota fiscal:

```
Unable to handle request. The action 'https://nfe.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/ws/lotenfe.asmx?WSDL' was not recognized.
```

Esse é o meu XML de envio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <TesteEnvioLoteRPS xmlns="http://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/nfe">
         <MensagemXML>...</MensagemXML>
      </TesteEnvioLoteRPS>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

E essas são minhas configurações de CURL

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $params['CURLOPT_URL']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $params['CURLOPT_SSLCERT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $params['CURLOPT_SSLKEY']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $params['CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params['CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $params['CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER']);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Alguma idéia?

Comment: Quais problemas?

Comment: Quando faço o envio é retornado: Unable to handle request. The action 'https://nfe.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/ws/lotenfe.asmx?WSDL' was not recognized.

Comment: como é feita a autenticação nesse web service? quando acesso a url via post no postman, recebo um erro 403, vc possivelmente precisa se autenticar tb

Comment: Uhnnn acho que estou errando nesse ponto, mas não é certeza. Vou verificar e retorno.

Comment: @RenatoTavares, provável que é a assinatura mesmo. Mas tentei outra abordagem utilizando um exemplo pronto. O que não resolveu muito, estou parado aqui: [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102780/1057-rejei%C3%A7%C3%A3o-assinatura-difere-do-calculado]